# Is there a way to check in a DataFrame, whether a value in a list in one column appears in a list in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns each with a list in such as:

```
Index    col1     col2
1     [2,3,4]   [5,6,7]
2     [1,2,3]     [2,3]
3     [9,6,2]       [9]
```

I want to be able to remove rows for which a value in column 2 appears in column 1.

I have tried:

```
df_dropped = df.drop(df[df["col2"] == (df["col1"])].index)
```

But this only removes lists that are the same, not if a value in one list appears in another.

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: change the condition to element in second list, you are comparing that both lists are the same if any([el in col2 for el in col1]) then remove the row

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: I tried: df = df.drop(any([x in df["col2"] for y in df["col1"]])) but this did not work

Comment: try a simple loop if any is confusing you:
to_drop = []
for a in df['col2']:
   for val in a;
     if val in df['col1']....

Comment: Thank you! The loop I used was: 
to_drop = []

for a in df.index:
    for val in df["col2"][a]:
        if val in df["col1"][a]:
            to_drop.append(a)
            
len(to_drop)

Comment: did it work then?

Comment: Yes it worked, drop the columns according to the index, thank you!